# »Auf etwas hindeuten« vs. »auf etwas hinweisen«

Tags: meaning, difference, synonym

Gibt es im Allgemeinen einen Unterschied zwischen *auf etwas hinweisen* und *auf etwas hindeuten*? In welchem Sinne? Sie sind ja Synonyme, aber ich vermute, dass eine bestimmte Nuance zwischen ihnen geben muss.

1. > Die Ergebnisse **wiesen darauf hin**, dass A und B die Nebenfolge dieser Krankheit sind.
2. > Die Ergebnisse **deuteten darauf hin**, dass A und B die Nebenfolge dieser Krankheit sind.

Comment: *Deuten* gibt nur eine grobe Richtung an. *Deuten* ist ein kurzer, wenig gezielter Fingerzeig: *Da lang.*

Comment: Aus dem Bauch heraus würde ich auch sagen, dass in gerade dem gewählten Kontext hindeuten nicht ganz passend ist. Man sagt ja auch nicht, dass bei der Polizei schon 35 Hindeutungen auf einen möglichen Tathergang eingegangen sind. Ich kann aber auch nicht sagen, woran genau es da hängt oder wie man die unterschiedliche Bedeutung an der Stelle definieren könnte.

Comment: Ich vermute nicht, dass es eine Nuance zwischen ihnen geben muss.

Comment: @hajef: Ist ein Beweis über das Hauptwort stichhaltig? Gilt für alle Paare von Verben, dass wenn sie synonym gebraucht werden auch die zugehörigen Substantive synonym gebraucht werden?

Comment: @userunknown Stichhaltig nicht, deshalb ist es ein Kommentar und keine Antwort. Es ist aber auf jeden Fall ein einfacher und wirksamer Weg, die Konnotationen der Wortstämme zu ermitteln.

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch denn dazu, hm?

Answer (score 2):

In meinem Sprachgebrauch, bzw. auch dem Sprachgebrauch meines Umfeldes gibt es hier durchaus feine Unterschiede zwischen den beiden Wörtern.

*Auf etwas hinweisen* impliziert eine relativ klare Folgerung aus einer Tatsache. Außerdem existiert das Substantiv *der Hinweis*, welches, wenn man es umwandelt, zu *hinweisen* und nicht zu *hindeuten* wird.
*Auf etwas hindeuten* ist dagegen eher eine mögliche Implikation: Wenn man aus einer Tatsache verschiedene Erkenntnisse/Vermutungen/Folgerungen ziehen kann, wird eher *deuten* verwendet. Wie Janka kommentierte, ist *deuten* lediglich eine grobe Richtung. Die Verwendung wird daher häufig mit Konjunktiv konstruiert.
Dinge können von verschiedenen Menschen verschieden *gedeutet* werden, ein Hinweiß dagegen ist meistens 'eindeutig'.

Bsp.:
Die Ergebnisse weisen darauf hin, dass A und B die Nebenfolgen dieser Krankheit sind.
Die Ergebnisse deuten darauf, dass entweder A oder B die Nebefolge der Krankheit sein könnte.

Ich kann jedoch nicht sagen, ob diese Regel allgemein im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum gültig ist, in meinem Umfeld ist es zumindest der Fall.

Comment: Ich sehe diesen Unterschied nicht. Man kann vor allem mit dem Finger auf einen Gegenstand weisen oder deuten. Ebenso kann man nur grob die Richtung weisen oder deuten. Dass die Lade-LED des Akkus an meinem Laptop nicht leuchtet deutet darauf hin/weist darauf hin, dass der Akku kaputt ist (könnte aber auch sein, dass nur die LED kaputt ist). Ein Quizmaster gibt dem Kandidaten noch einen Hinweis - trotzdem kommt der nicht drauf, dass Rubens gemeint ist - so deutlich müssen Hinweise nicht sein.

Comment: Wie könnte man das denn herausfinden? Wie kann man die Aussage auf eine breitere Evidenzbasis stellen als nur auf die des eigenen Sprachgefühls und das des "eigenen Umfelds"?

Comment: Ich nehme das auch so wahr; _auf etw. hindeuten_ ist etwas weniger intensiv als _auf etw. hinweisen_. Der Unterschied ist aber sehr fein und im Grunde ohnehin überhaupt nur dann potenziell wahrnehmbar, wenn die beiden Wörter zusammen auftreten.

Answer (score 1):

Also bei uns würde ich sagen verwendet man **hindeuten** wenn mich jemand fragt "Wo ist ...", dann deute ich ihm die Richtung. 
**Hinweisen** verwende ich falls ich einen Fehler finde und den jenigen darauf hinweise. Alles nur Beispiele es gibt natürlich mehrere Fälle :)

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, das *hindeuten* in der Art verwendet wird. Das wäre einfach *deuten*, so wie du es selbst geschrieben hast.

Comment: Zudem fehlt im Text das *h* in *i[h]m".

Comment: @vectory Für solche Fälle hat StackExchange den "edit" Button... Außerdem ist die Verwendung so wie ich es geschrieben habe auch Beispiel Nr. 1 des Duden! 
https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hindeuten

Comment: Deren einziges Beispiel betrifft die abstrakte Bedeutung Nr. 3. Die Bedeutung Nr. 1 ist sicherlich im Sprachgebrauch zu finden, so wie viele Stilblüten, aber ich halte es nicht für die primäre Bezeichnung.

Answer (score 0):

In aller Kürze: Für mich sind [hinweisen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/hinweisen) und [hindeuten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/hindeuten) Synonyme [ohne](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=kern;q=hindeuten) [Unterschiede](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=kern;q=hinweisen). Einzig wird hinweisen noch im Zusammenhang von

> jemandes Aufmerksamkeit auf etwas lenken, jemanden (besonders durch eine Äußerung) auf etwas aufmerksam machen

verwendet und im Allgemeinen (und auch deswegen) [deutlich häufiger](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hinweisen%2C%20hindeuten&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chinweisen%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhinweisen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHinweisen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chindeuten%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhindeuten%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHindeuten%3B%2Cc0) benutzt.

Answer (score 0):

Dem Bsp. nach gibt es keinen Unterschied. Soweit schließe ich mich @UU's Kommentaren an.

In anderem Kontext, *jemanden auf etwas hinweisen* gibt es keine Alternative mit *hindeuten*. Überhaupt wird *hindeuten* meiner Meinung nach sonst nicht verwendet, allenfalls als eher seltene Mischform aus *deuten* und *hinweisen*.

Vgl. auch *andeuten* und *anweisen*, die sich weitgehend unterscheiden.

---

Zwar sind Bemerkungen zum Indo-Europäischen hier eher unangebracht, doch ich möchte festhalten, dass *da*, *das da* (tada?) Nähe suggeriert und insofern im Kontrast zu *Weite* steht. Ob dies hierher gehört sei dahingestellt, ebenso wie etwaige Vergleiche zu *Deut*, *video*, *weiß*, *weise*, *Weise*, *wissen*, *Weg, Zweck, Bedeutung, tüdeln, zeigen, zeugen* etc. etc.